Verwendung von "sein" + Infinitiv: "ich war arbeiten"
Vielleicht wurde diese Frage hier schon einmal gestellt, aber ich konnte nichts Ähnliches finden. Ich unterhielt mich mit einem Freund aus Hannover, wo ich ebenfalls wohne, und dey benutzte den folgenden Satz:
Mir geht's sogar wieder so gut, dass ich heute wieder arbeiten war.
Obwohl ich den allgemeinen Sinn verstand, fiel mir etwas Ungewöhnliches auf: ich war arbeiten. Es schien, als wäre ich dieser Form zum ersten Mal begegnet, und sie erinnerte mich an das Past Continuous im Englischen sowie an das am-Progressiv im Deutschen. Als ich nachfragte, sagte mein Freund, dass sie umgangssprachlich sei und im Alltag weit verbreitet verwendet werde.
Ich fragte auch, ob dey einen Unterschied zwischen diesem Ausdruck und ich habe heute gearbeitet sieht, wobei ich vermutete, dass Letzteres hauptsächlich die Tatsache des Arbeitens feststellt, während war arbeiten die kontinuierliche Natur der Handlung betont. Dey stimmte zu, dass es einen Unterschied gibt, und erwähnte auch das Plusquamperfekt, aber ich verstand nicht ganz, wie das in deren Erklärung passte.
Habt ihr diese Form schon einmal gehört? Verwendet ihr sie selbst? Würdet ihr sie als deutschen Ersatz für das Continuous Tense betrachten, oder denkt ihr, dass sie einen anderen Zweck erfüllt?
Und zuletzt: Sollte ich anfangen, sie selbst im Alltag zu verwenden?
Änderung: Es scheint, dass ich verstanden habe, worum es geht: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv. Wenn das gemeint wurde, wird die Bemerkung über das Plusquamperfekt viel verständlicher.

Offtopic für mitlesende Lernende der deutschen Sprache; "Dey" ist natürlich kein Standarddeutsch, es soll "die genannte Person, deren Geschlecht hier keine Rolle spielen soll" bedeuten, ist ein ausgedachtes Pronomen im Alpha-Teststadium und wird einem sonst nur auf den üblichen Spielwiesen für solche Alphatests begegnen (Unis, andere steuerfinanzierte Oasen, TikTok etc.).

@HalvarF Wie würdest du eine Person nennen, deren Geschlecht du nicht kennst oder nicht erwähnen möchtest?

@aldin Natürlich würde ich diese Person, die du ja kennst, mit dem richtigen Partizip bezeichnen. Wenn ich sie nicht kenne, mit dem generischen Maskulinum ;-).

Die Konstruktion sein+Infinitiv wird als Absentiv bezeichnet. Sie drückt aus, dass

man einen Ort verlassen hat,
um einer Tätigkeit nachzugehen,
und dann irgendwann wiederkommen wird.

Die Tätigkeit gilt hier üblicherweise in erster Linie als Begründung für die Abwesenheit, aber das muss nicht der Fall sein, wie in deinem Beispiel.
Während ein am-Progressiv eher ausdrückt, dass man wegen etwas beschäftigt ist, drückt der Absentiv aus, dass man wegen etwas weg ist.

Ich kann nicht, ich bin arbeiten.

kann man also nicht verwenden, wenn jemand einem beim Homeoffice stört. Mehr Beispiele finden sich im Wikipedia-Artikel.
Manche Verwendungen vom englischen continuous tense lassen sich mit Absentiv übersetzen, wie "I was working". Aber "Ich bin mal den Müll rausbringen." kann man nicht mit continuous tense übersetzen; genauso wie "I'm going to Berlin" weder mit Absentiv noch mit "am"-Progressiv übersetzt werden kann.
Ich verwende die Form häufig. Die Form ist zwar umgangssprachlich, aber zumindestens für mich nicht sehr stark markiert.

Vielen Dank! Ich habe gerade auch das Wikipedia-Artikel übers Absentiv gefunden, und dein Beitrag hat meine Gedanken bestätigt.

This construction is also common in Dutch, and it is also a bit informal. Might it be more common in lower Germany than in upper Germany?
